# How to run nx e2e tests with tags in angular NX workspace?

Tags: angular, cucumber, cypress, gherkin, nrwl-nx

I have angular NX workspace with e2e test cases(cypress) and integrated with cucumber. I currently run tests using the command

```
nx e2e <projectName> --baseUrl= adc.com
```

Also to test the affected apps I run

```
nx affected:e2e --baseUrl adc.com
```

I am working on running specific test files using tags. So far I couldn't find a way to run with tags.

I tried running with

```
nx e2e <projectName> --baseUrl= adc.com --tags= '@Regression'
```

but it didn't work out and ran all the tests.

I have tags defined as below.

**@Regression**
Feature : The core
Scenario : Test the page
Given ....
When ...
Then ...
And ...

Comment: How are you applying tags in your tests. Please add that info to your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I apply tags on the feature file scenarios . For example. @E2E
Feature: The core

Scenario: Opening the page
Given The user opens my page
When The user clicks the tab on my page
Then The url path should include somename
And  The title should be shown

Comment: @saikumark did you get resolution for this query ?